# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

Our MySQL server keeps giving us this message. And it's a constant thing, I will restart it then 5 minutes, or 30 minutes later I will just get this error again. I've been googling like crazy to fix it, I have tried using chmod `/var/lib/mysql` and `/var/run/mysqld`, all sorts of things and I have no idea how to fix it, Im getting desperate because Im going to lose money if I can't get it sorted.

Here's my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file 
http://178.62.26.90/ben/my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in error log?

```
/var/log/mysql/error.log
```

It would be easier. It looks like your instance crashes, but in the error log there will be more details about why.